# How strong is Church's type theory?

Tags: logic, foundations, type-theory

[This article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory-church/#ElemTypeTheo) on the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy describes "Church's type theory", i.e. the simply typed lambda calculus together with a set of inference rules and a set of axioms which turn it into a logical system capable of stating and proving mathematical propositions. How strong is this system, relative to more commonly used systems such as ZFC? Would it suffice as a foundation for mathematics?

Comment: Please provide examples of systems that "would suffice as a foundation for mathematics" and systems that don't, to help calibrate how you'd like this question answered. For some of us, Heyting arithmetic satisfies everything we might demand from a foundation; for others, even ZFC+an infinite hierarchy of inaccessibles is nowhere near enough.